# Connecting Arduino Yún with Processing - JSCH

Tags: java, ssh, arduino, processing, arduino-yun

I recently bought Arduino Yún, and I´m trying to use the data of analog pins with Processing and broadcaste with OSC to other applications.

I´m using this code from Proccesing forum (I didn´t receive answers) but I don´t know how to use this code inside my processing code.

```
    // jsch is an open source SSH client for Java. 
    // get it from <a href="http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/</a>

import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;
import java.io.*;

String user = "root";
String password = "<ARDUINO PASSWORD>";
String host = "arduino.local";
int port=22;

try
{
  JSch jsch = new JSch();
  Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
  session.setPassword(password);
  session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");  // less than maximally secure
  System.out.println("Establishing Connection...");
  session.connect();
  System.out.println("Connection established.");
  Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");

  // this stream will be used to send data to the Yun
  DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(channel.getOutputStream());
  channel.setInputStream(null);

  // this jsch member class provides remote execution of a shell command
  ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand("telnet localhost 6571");
  // see <a href="http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoYun#toc17" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoYun#toc17</a> for why this command

    ((ChannelExec)channel).setErrStream(System.err);
  InputStream in=channel.getInputStream();

  // after configuring all channel parameters, we connect, causing the
  // command to be executed. Results and further input will be handled
  // by the streams
  channel.connect();

  byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];

  // poll input stream forever
  while (true) {
    while (in.available ()>0) {
      int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
      if (i<0)break;
      System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
    }
    if (channel.isClosed()) {
      System.out.println("exit-status: "+channel.getExitStatus());
      break;
    }
    try {
      // if used with the Console example code, this will blink the LED
      // in time with polling events
      dataOut.writeBytes("L\n");
      dataOut.flush();
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      dataOut.writeBytes("H\n");
      dataOut.flush();
    }
    catch(Exception ee) {
      System.err.print(ee);
    }
  }
  System.out.println("disconnecting...\n");
  channel.disconnect();
  session.disconnect();
  System.out.println("Finished.\n");
}
catch(Exception e) {
  System.err.print(e);
}
```

Can anybody give some instructions to use Arduino Yún and manipulate their data in Processing?

Thanks!